# How to combine cardviews with a common element under one cardview in recyclerview?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, cardview

I'm having difficulties with cardview and recyclerview. To be specific I want to create a card view containing user input. If user then makes another input containing a common element (like a date of the month) I want the two card views to combine into one with a row above summarizing the information below. Like shown in the pictures below.

[Cardview Image containing 1 set of user inputs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cNWpv.jpg)

(T. stand for total)

After we get the first CardView and user inputs more information regarding the same date I want to combine them like in the next picture.

[Cardview image containing three sets of user input for the same date.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D1cE1.jpg)

I will be thankful for any help. I just need the right approach. 
If providing code sample please use Kotlin if possible. Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: Welcome!  Looks like an excellent first post, but you might consider making the images display inline because more people will look at them if they don't have to click.  See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Comment: Thank you for the advice Glen. I tried it but a message was presented that I need 10 reputation points to post images.